# Why is $L=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ if $ \{\alpha_1 ,\dots, \alpha_n \} $ is a basis of L/K?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was trying to prove the equivalence of the following conditions for $L/K$ a field extension of a field $K$:

1. $L/K$ is finite.
2. $L/K$ is algebraic and  finitely generated.
3. There exists algebraic elements over $K$: $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n \in L$ such that $L=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$.

When showing $(1\Rightarrow 2)$ I reasoned the following:

If $L/K$ is finite, then $[K(\alpha):K]\leq [L:K] < \infty$ $\forall \alpha \in L$. Therefore, every $\alpha \in L$ is algebraic over $K$. Then, let it be $ \{ \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \} $ a basis for $L/K$. I want to show that $L=K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ and so we could conclude that $L/K$  is finitely generated.

I thought that as $K(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is the smallest extension of $K$ which contains $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, this must be related to the fact that this ones make a basis for $L/K$, but I can not write it clearly.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ is a basis then these elements generate $L$ as a $K$-vector space. So every element in $L$ can be written as a linear combination of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ with coefficients in $K$. Clearly, every such element belongs to $K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. So indeed $L=K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$.

However, note that a basis and a generating set are not the same thing. A basis is always a generating set of the field extension (by the above argument), but the converse is not true in general.

Comment: Thanks! True, a generating set nor even has to be independent.